# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in LLVM SimplifyCFGOpt::run

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing a toy compiler with LLVM. I ran it with the following input

```
int main() { int a = *0x400; if (a > 123) { return 42; } else { return 24; } }
```

and it generates the following LLVM IR

```
define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %ret = alloca i32, align 4
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %deref = load i32, ptr inttoptr (i32 1024 to ptr), align 4
  store i32 %deref, ptr %a, align 4
  %a2 = load i32, ptr %a, align 4
  %cmptmp = icmp sgt i32 %a2, 123
  br i1 %cmptmp, label %then, label %else

retblock:                                         ; preds = %else, %then
  %ret1 = load i32, ptr %ret, align 4
  ret i32 %ret1

then:                                             ; preds = %entry
  store i32 42, ptr %ret, align 4
  br label %retblock
  br label %merge

else:                                             ; preds = %entry
  store i32 24, ptr %ret, align 4
  br label %retblock
  br label %merge

merge:                                            ; preds = %else, %then
  ret void
}
```

When I try to compile the IR, it crashes with the following exception

```
Process 79188 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xbeaddfdd9808)
    frame #0: 0x0000000103161198 rs-05279ee6318c53df`(anonymous namespace)::SimplifyCFGOpt::run(llvm::BasicBlock*) + 9264
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong from the IR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You LLVM IR is invalid – you're having multiple terminator instructions in your basic blocks. Always run IR verifier, it will told you so.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing the `merge` block and double checking all my branch pointers between blocks